# Animate an icon by using serious of Lat/lon Array - Mapbox js

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am modifying bellow script to see how can i move an Icon by following Array of Lat/lon  , but it always say error such , but I am providing as an Array

Can any one please help me to understand what i am doing wrong ? 
I am revering this example 
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-marker/

```
Error : 
lng_lat.js:121 Uncaught Error: `LngLatLike` argument must be specified as a LngLat instance, an object {lng: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, an object {lon: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, or an array of [<lng>, <lat>]
    at Function.yu.convert (lng_lat.js:121)
    at o.setLngLat (marker.js:251)
    at animateMarker (animate.html:33)
```

Modified Code : -

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Animate a marker</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.51.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.51.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = '';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [90.35388165034988, 23.725173272533567],
    zoom: 10
});

var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker();

function animateMarker() {
    var radius = 20;

    // Update the data to a new position based on the animation timestamp. The
    // divisor in the expression `timestamp / 1000` controls the animation speed.
    marker.setLngLat([
 
 [90.35388165034988, 23.725173272533567],
 [90.37379437008741, 23.732873570085644] ,
 [90.38563900508132, 23.72297310398119],
 [90.35388165034988, 23.725173272533567],
 [90.35388165034988, 23.725173272533567]
  
    ]);

    // Ensure it's added to the map. This is safe to call if it's already added.
    marker.addTo(map);

    // Request the next frame of the animation.
    requestAnimationFrame(animateMarker);
}

// Start the animation.
requestAnimationFrame(animateMarker);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass a single coordinate to `setLngLat`.  You cannot pass an array.  Here's a crude example where inside the animation function, we use time to pick a position from the array of points and pass *that one position* to the marker.

```
var controlPoints = [
 [90.35388165034988, 23.725173272533567],
 [90.37379437008741, 23.732873570085644] ,
 [90.38563900508132, 23.72297310398119],
 [90.35388165034988, 23.725173272533567],
 [90.35388165034988, 23.725173272533567]
];

function animateMarker(timestamp) {
    // stay at each point for 1 second, then move to the next
    // (lower 1000 to 500 to move 2x as fast)
    var position = Math.floor(timestamp / 1000) % controlPoints.length;
    marker.setLngLat(controlPoints[position])

    // Ensure it's added to the map. This is safe to call if it's already added.
    marker.addTo(map);

    // Request the next frame of the animation.
    requestAnimationFrame(animateMarker);
}
```

This animation will be crude.  Ideally, you'd take those control points and create a polyline or linear ring, then your animation function would interpolate along the polyline at a set speed (like 30 km/s).  You would end up with a very nice animation that followed the path of the control points.

Comment: Thanks, Yes i can see the idea now

so we just need to  implement it with this example
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-line/

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` is fairly new to the JS standard. It's not supported by IE 8 < or Netscape Navigator. I would use `setTimeout` instead, where possible.

Comment: @Brandon, when you say set 30 km/s, how do i do that ?

Comment: @gilbert-v , "setTimeout"  is this with requesntAnimationFrame ? or with other function ?
Thanks

Comment: @gilbert-v that’s what polyfills are for. Michael that’s a good Q for this site.

Comment: @Brandon  , Thanks but please let me know what you meant by set 30 km/s , how do i set that ? 
i already implemented it with polylines, looks very nice,

Comment: it is complicated.  You should ask a new question specifically about how to control the speed of your map animation.  Specify if you want to control it in terms of screen space (e.g.'I want it to move X pixels per second') or you want to control it in terms of map space (e.g. 'I want it to move X km per second')